# A successful iOS SDK photo upload does not show on news feed, but does on user's wall

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, upload, photo, feed

Using this standard code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[params setObject:image forKey:@"photo"];
[params setObject:text forKey:@"caption"];
[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                          andParams:params
                      andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                        andDelegate:self];
```

I am able to successfully post a photo to the logged-in user's timeline. I have yet to see this photo show up on the newsfeed of people who follow this user though. For my image uploading app, it seems that having the uploaded photo show in the friends news feeds should happen. What can I do to ensure that this successfully uploaded photo gets added to the user's timeline **AND** the user's friends newsfeeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is (intentionally) under Facebook's control. Your photos may or may not show up in news feeds; they might also show up, but be combined into a single item. I don't think there is any way to force them to show up in news feeds.

Comment: Is there any documentation that specifies this?